# modules not getting processed by puppet-agent

Tags: puppet

On our puppet box ( under the puppet/modules folder ) , I have added a module for installing a package. I then added the classes needed for the resources into the init.pp ( and other derived class files ) into the manifests folder. I configured these classes and the corresponding nodes associated with them in the puppet dashboard.

When I run puppet-agent with the environment flag , I see that puppet does not run my module. It is running couple of other modules defined similarly on the box alongside my module , but not my module.

What configuration is needed so puppet-agent picks up a module and runs the manifests it defines ? For simplicity , I want to do this on one box first.

Answer (score 1):

So, a module is a great way to create a contained re-usable class. However, to deploy a module, it has to be called/defined, which is not done by default.

You can do this one of two ways -- if it's a one time sort of thing, you can simple do a;
puppet apply -e 'module' on the agent and that should apply the module (or give you an error ;)!)

However, if it's something you wanted to permanently alter... I'd do something like this.

Create file called nodes.pp @ /etc/puppet/manifests
In nodes.pp;

> node 'test.domain.com' { include modulename }

Then in site.pp @ /etc/puppet/manifests, you just have to make sure at the top there is;

> import 'nodes.pp'

Then you can run like a puppet agent -t and you'll see it attempt to get the module.

Answer (score 0):

You should include module in your init.pp or dependent modules so that it will be visible during dependency check.